# Mail couldn't send using gmail smtp in php localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, localhost

I'm trying to send emails from my php localhost.

I edited the following files according to a working tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho)

`php.ini` and `sendmail.ini`

Used gmail smtp server in `sendmail.ini`

`smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com`

`smtp_port=587`

`auth_username=myemail
auth_password=mypass`

When I tried to send the mail, there isn't any error but the mail isn't receiving.

Can anybody tell me where did I go wrong? Should I change anything in the gmail account which I used for the authentication in `sendmail.ini` ?

Comment: Try to get the error message, or maybe the mail is in the spam folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Comment: @GerbenJacobs: I checked the spam folder, but it's not there. I will try to get the error message.

Comment: @AMS: I don't think this is the right solution for this localhost.

Comment: @GerbenJacobs, sorry but how can I get an error message for this function?

Comment: I don't know, you should show some code so people can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that you can use gmail as your local smtp server. The link was given as a trivial information. If you want to use the mail() function of PHP via Gmail maybe you should look at the one I gave you or use your FAI smtp or install a smtp server on your machine. I may be wrong but using some smtp servers sometimes requires you to first connect via pop or imap and then you can use the smtp.

Comment: In the example given in the question, it works really well for 90% of the people who tried it. So that's why I got this doubt.

Comment: my bad post your sendmail.ini maybe you forgot something, and post your mail() function.